# Finding a percentage of a table column

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table that has the following columns path, time, status, id, and method. I want to select all rows that have a method which is not '200 OK' and calculate the percentage for each time a request was made to that path. I have tried the following:

```
select time as day, 
(count(status) * 100 / (select count(*) from log)) as error 
from log 
where status != '200 OK' group by day;

select time as day,
(count(status) * 100.0 / (select count(*) from log where status != '200OK')) as errors 
from log 
where status != '200 OK' group by time order by errors DESC
```

The queries that I have tried I am not 100% sure on what is actually being computed so if you can help please provide some details of what the query is doing. Thanks to all who help. Below is the table with a few rows. I tried to line it up as best as possible.

```
path               |ip             |method| status        |time       |id
/path-to-page-A/   |198.51.100.195 |GET   | 200 OK        |2016-07-01 07:00:00+00| 23 
/path-to-page-B/   |192.0.2.80     |GET   | 404 Not Found |2016-07-01 07:00:00+00| 24
/path-to-page-C/   |192.0.2.81     |GET   | 404 Not Found |2016-07-01 07:00:00+00| 25        
/path-to-page-A/   |198.51.100.195 |GET   | 200 OK        |2016-08-01 07:00:00+00| 26
```

Comment: You say that you want a percentage for each path (I think) so you should be grouping by path.  You say "method which is not '200 OK'" but that looks like a status and that is what your SQL says.  If you could give the table definition and a few rows of sample data (5 to 10 rows would probably be enough), then it would probably be easy to help you.  Your expected answers for the sample data would help too.  Right now, I'm guessing too much, and therefore likely to be wrong.

Comment: @RonBallard Thank you for your reply. I have added some sample data that will hopefully shed light on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I added an extra row to make it a bit more interesting:

```
create table log
(
    path      varchar(16),
    ip        varchar(16),
    method    varchar(8),
    status    varchar(16),
    time      timestamp,
    id        integer
);

insert into log(path, ip, method, status, time, id ) values ('/path-to-page-A/','198.51.100.195','GET','200 OK',       '2016-07-01 07:00:00+00', 23); 
insert into log(path, ip, method, status, time, id ) values ('/path-to-page-B/','192.0.2.80',    'GET','404 Not Found','2016-07-01 07:00:00+00', 24);
insert into log(path, ip, method, status, time, id ) values ('/path-to-page-C/','192.0.2.81',    'GET','404 Not Found','2016-07-01 07:00:00+00', 25);       
insert into log(path, ip, method, status, time, id ) values ('/path-to-page-A/','198.51.100.195','GET','200 OK',       '2016-08-01 07:00:00+00', 26);
insert into log(path, ip, method, status, time, id ) values ('/path-to-page-B/','192.0.2.80',    'GET','200 OK',       '2016-07-01 07:00:00+00', 30);
```

The Query:

```
select
    a.path,
    coalesce(b.failed_requests, 0) * 100 / a.all_requests as percent_failed
from
    (
        select
            path,
            count(*) as all_requests
        from
            log
        group by
            path
    ) a
    left outer join
    (
        select
            path,
            count(*) as failed_requests
        from
            log
        where
            status <> '200 OK'
        group by
            path
    ) b
    on a.path = b.path;
```

The Results:

```
       path       | percent_failed 
------------------+----------------
 /path-to-page-B/ |             50
 /path-to-page-A/ |              0
 /path-to-page-C/ |            100
(3 rows)
```

Feel free to comment if you need more explanation.

Comment: I'm sorry can you briefly explain the above query. My SQL is still newbish.

Comment: The sub-query labelled "a" counts all requests for each path.
The sub-query labelled "b" counts all failed requests for each path.
We have to do these separately because the rows we are considering are different.
We then join these 2 queries together so that we have both counts for each path.
It has to be an outer join because some paths have no failures.  In  these cases the failed_requests count is null, so we have to change it to zero.
A good free source of information is: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp.  My contribution is: http://www.thedatastudio.net.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a case to help with the calculation.

```
SELECT path, SUM(CASE WHEN status != '200 OK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(path) AS error
FROM log
GROUP BY path
```